# Laravel - PHPUnit simple test failed

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5

I don't understand... Very first test `phpunit` works fine.
Then I added new Route and new method of course.

```
Route::get( '/about', 'HomeController@about' );
```

So, I changed the line inside ExampleTest:

```
public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $response = $this->call('GET', '/about');

        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
    }
```

And this gives me an error:
`Failed asserting that 302 matches expected 200.`

What I was doing wrong?

Comment: What is in your HomeController? Are you redirecting in there?

Comment: Just a `return "Hello"`

Comment: Oh! My mistake. I have a `$this->middleware('auth');` :D

Answer (score 0):

```
public function testBasicExample()
{
    $response = $this->call('GET', '/about')->response;

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->status());
}
```